# I cannot type the letter "c" on my iMac G5

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I have an iMac G5 running Mac OS X 10.5.8. Unfortunately I cannot type <kbd>c</kbd>. I have tried both wired and wireless keyboard, and both bluetooth and USB-dongle wireless. Even over VNC from my (somewhat more current) iMac, I cannot type the <kbd>c</kbd> key.

Each time I press the <kbd>c</kbd> key it plays the "Funk" error noise (sometimes after a delay of a few seconds).

I am able to copy and paste the letter "c" from a file which already contained the letter "c".

Answer (score 4):

[This article from Mac World](https://www.macworld.com/article/3209726/when-youre-sometimes-unable-to-type-a-certain-character-on-your-mac-heres-how-to-troubleshoot-it.html) (for macOS 10.12.5, not Mac OS X 10.5.8) suggests that the key could have been set up to speak the selected text.

This would consistent with the "Funk" error noise each time I pressed the <kbd>c</kbd> key, because there was no text selected for it to read out! I tested this by selecting some text and, lo and behold, it read the text out.

The interface in macOS 10.12.5 is different enough that it's not clear where to find the settings from the article.

Open System Preferences and click "Speech".

[image: System Preferences with Speech button highlighted]

Click "Text to Speech" in the tab bar and then, next to the "Speak selected text when the key is pressed" click the "Set Key..." button.

[image: Text to Speech tab of Speech pane of System Preferences with Text to Speech tab button and Set Key button highlighted]

Chose a new key combination (mine was set to <kbd>c</kbd><sup>1</sup>). I changed it to <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image: Set a key combination popup with OK button highlighted]

I can now type the <kbd>c</kbd> key!

---

<sup>1</sup> It was actually set to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. Why this was being triggered without Caps Lock being turned on or depressed I am unsure.